# css animation is running even when i switch tabs

Tags: javascript, loops

I made a loop for a simple animation on my website, and it is running when i switch tabs. the rest of my website does not do this, so that one difference messes everything up. Is there any way i can make it only run when i am on my website-tab?

Code for the animation:

```js
var i = 1;

function loop1() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("dollarAnim").animate([
                { opacity: "0" },
                { opacity: "1" },
                { opacity: "0" },
            ], {
                duration: 10000,
                iterations: 1,
            });
            if (i > 0) {
                loop1();
            }

        }, 20000)
    }

    loop1();
```

```html
<div id="dollarAnim" style="opacity: 0;">$</div>
```

Comment: You can use the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) to detect tab focus/blur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add an event listener to window, when the user leaves:

```
window.addEventListener("blur", function stopAnimation(){});
```

and when focus again start animation:

```
window.addEventListener("focus", function sartAnimation(){});
```